# Converting excel cell content in to html mark up

Tags: html, excel, csv

I have a csv file with cell content, I am uploading it to a website and want certain parts to be in html mark up.

Each cell has multiple lines of text, and looks like this:

```
• person name, person details
• person name, person details
• person name, person details
```

I have managed to convert this into html mark up in the cell to the right so that it looks like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>person name, person details</li>
 <li>person name, person details</li>
 <li>person name, person details</li>
</ul>
```

To do so I have used this formula (J26 being the cell to the left of the cell containing this formula):

```
=IF((IFERROR(FIND("•",J26),)), LEFT(J26,SEARCH("•",J26)-1)&"<ul><li>"&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(J26,LEN(J26)-SEARCH("•",J26)),"•","</li><li>")&"</li></ul>","")
```

All I need to do now is to add some logic so that the html list is formatted with the beginning part of each list item in a span tag - like this:

```
<ul>
 <li><span>person name</span>, person details</li>
 <li><span>person name</span>, person details</li>
 <li><span>person name</span>, person details</li>
</ul>
```

This part I am struggling with and can't work out the logic.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND("•",J26),), SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(J26,SEARCH("•",J26)-1)&"<ul><li><span>"&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(J26,LEN(J26)-SEARCH("•",J26)),"•","</li><li><span>"),",","</span>,")&"</li></ul>","")
```

Comment: Hi Pnuts, That works 100% and is exactly what I am looking for, thanks very much for your efforts! Regards,